# Visual C# "Settings Editor" within application?

Tags: c#, .net, settings

Is there an easy way to wrap a "Preferences Panel" thing around the `Settings.settings` file (or any other settings file)?

Basically I have a bunch of strings stored in `Settings.settings`, and want to have a form where the user can edit these..

I could add a bunch of TextBoxes, and have a button that does `Properties.blah = this.blahInput.Text; Properties.Save();` for each, but this feels like reinventing the wheel..

*Edit:* The PropertyGrid control (as suggested by [bassfriend's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846144/visual-c-settings-editor-within-application/846163#846163)) seems perfect, but I cannot work out how to bind the property grid's SelectedObject to `Properties.Settings.Default` - When I try I get the following error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'MyProject.Properties.Settings' to 'object[]'
```

Comment: Re your edit - it sounds like you're accidentally using `SelectedObjects`. You have to use `SelectedObject` (singular).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Maybe you want to take a look at the [PropertyGrid Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.propertygrid.aspx).

Comment: For the record - there is also a WPF PropertyGrid over at CodePlex http://www.codeplex.com/wpg

Answer (score 5):

I had no problem:

```
        propertyGrid1.SelectedObject = Properties.Settings.Default;
```

I did have to change the visibility to Public in the Settings Designer.

Comment: Opps, I was trying to set "SelectedObjects", not "SelectedObject".. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to use the Settings.Default.Properties property? That returns SettingsPropertyCollection which should be convertable to an object[].